# The difference between {\x >\y} and {\x >? \y} in xfp package?

Tags: xfp

On page 1/2 of [xfp package](https://mirror.las.iastate.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/l3packages/xfp.pdf) we see `x >? y` as a valid comparison operator. Is it different from `x>y`?
I think they are equivalent based on my following code, but not sure:

```
  \documentclass{article}

\usepackage{,xfp}

\begin{document}

\edef\x{5}
\edef\y{6}
\fpeval{\x>? \y}\\
\fpeval{\x> \y}
\end{document}
```

The result for both is zero. So are they equivalent in general?

Comment: May I ask where to find the documentation for x ?y

Comment: 1) `\fpeval` is just a wrapper of latex3 function `\fp_eval:n` (documented in [`interface3`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf)) which accepts a floating point expression. 2) From the doc, sec. XXIII.9.3, a relation operator should consists of a non-empty string of `<`, `=`, `>`, and `?`, optionally preceded by `!`, and may not start with `?`. 3) Hence `\x >? \y` means if `\x` is greater than or not ordered with `\y`.

Comment: @HenriMenke Thanks for pointing out that. I should be more cautious.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The question mark `?` is the “not ordered” comparison of `l3fp`.  More or less quoting from the documentation of `\fp_compare_p:nNn`:

> `x ? y` is true if `x` and `y` are “not ordered” which occurs exactly if one or both operands is `nan` or is a tuple.  Note that `nan` is distinct from any other value, even from itself, i.e. if `x = nan` then `x == x` is false.  To test whether a value is `nan` you can use the “not ordered” comparison with any other value, e.g. `x ? 0`.

That also means that if neither `x` nor `y` are `nan` or a tuple, the comparison `x >? y` will be equivalent to `x > y`.

---

*Personal note:*  I'm rather skeptical of the usefulness of this “not ordered” comparison.  It seems to me that this is trying to solve a problem that is already covered by other operators.  For example in a traditional programming language, like C, you can check for `nan` by checking whether a value is equal to itself, i.e. `x == x` will only ever be false, if `x` is `nan`.  For comparison between tuples, all operators should just return `false` (or better throw a type error), except for `==` and `!=` which ought to perform and element-wise comparison.

Comment: Would you please put a link you quoted from l3fp?

Comment: @Aria No, the `interface3.pdf` documentation doesn't have stable hyperlink targets, so the next time it updates, the link will be wrong.  For now you can use this link: http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf#HD.819

Comment: Enrico ('egreg') is working on a proper user documentation file for `xfp`, as it's a bit terse ATM

Comment: I'm sorry to ask such trivial questions, but I didn't understand. What in practice is an “not ordered” comparison? What is a “ordered” comparison ? What is nan?

Comment: @AndréC Please refer to the great article [What Every Computer ScientistShould Know About Floating PointArithmetic](https://cr.yp.to/2005-590/goldberg.pdf) (or just Google?) for these details.

Comment: @HenriMenke Oh yes, if it takes 78 pages to explain that, it's really complicated. It makes me feel less stupid. :-)